# Is it safe to send vulnerable information as function arguments in PHP?

Tags: php, function, arguments, argument-passing

I have two functions: `get_post_data()` gets the POST data from a form. It then sends the username and password to `process_login($username, $password)`. I want to send the password in plain-text.

Am I safe to do this, or do I have to hash/encrypt the password before I send it as a function argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashing should be done when storing the password to a permanent location, or obviously when you need to check it against the stored hash.

Otherwise, if you're transferring it from one server to another or an external resource I would think it would be better practice to hash it and or at minimum use an encrypted connection. Preferably both.

Comment: So it's safe to send passwords as function arguments?

Comment: yes, you're going to pass it around as you work with it, so that's normal, it's when you store or send the secure info to another location that you want to hash it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are safe, hashing should be done server side to prevent inconsistencies in client side hash implementations.

Once you have the variable in your php code, passing it around your own functions is safe, a user wont have access to this.

If you are worried about transmitting the password from client to server over plain-text, you should look into using https.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with having

```
$password = 'some piece of malicious code';

process_login($password);
```

because that malicious code would only ever be transferred around as DATA, and never actually executed.

Now, if you were doing something silly (ok, this would be downright stupid):

```
eval($password);
```

then yes, you would be vulnerable to getting your system completely subverted.